# Intel 8086 assembly: add/sub very large number?

Tags: assembly

How to add or sub very large numbers in the x86 assembly?

E.g input:

first line: max. 20 digit number
second line: +/- 
third line: max. 20 digit number

And these lines repeat when the user exit to program.

does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ADC (add with carry) instruction is your friend here. This operation is the same for any assembler:

1. clear the carry bit
2. point at the first word of large operand 1
3. point at the first word of large operand 2
4. point at the result words
5. loop for the number of words in your operands:
6. use ADC on the current word of each operand, storing the result in your result
7. increment all the pointers by one word.

The carry flag will indicate whether the addition overflowed.

For subtraction, negate the second operand first.

edit: you asked for an example. Here is some (probably horrible) 80386 code to add 2 double words together. Caveat: I have not written assembly language for 20 years.

```
section .text
    global _start         ;must be declared for using gcc

_start:                  ;tell linker entry point

    clc                  ; clear carry flag
    mov ecx, len        ;calculation length in ecx
    mov esi, 0           ; esi is index register into array of longwords
myLoop:
    mov eax, [operand1+esi*4] ; move operand1 into register A
    adc eax, [operand2+esi*4] ; add with carry operand 2 into register A
    mov [result+esi*4], eax ; store register a into result
    inc esi                 ; increment index
    loop myLoop             ; decrement count of words to do and jump if not zero

    ; at this point the answer will be in result...result+7, low order words first

    mov eax, 1          ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80            ;call kernel

section .data

operand1 dd 0,10 ;low order words first. value = 10 * 4.2bn 
operand2 dd 0,20 ; low order words first. value = 20 * 4.2bn
result dd 0,0
len equ ($ - result)/4          ;number of words in each operand
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Perhaps, could you show an example ?

Comment: For subtraction, use the `SBB` instruction (not the `ADC` instruction).

Comment: :-) Suggest you buy a book on 80x86 assembler. It's a big topic to teach in 600 characters...

Comment: Thank you Richard :) sorry, but I need a 8086 program, because in this required.

Comment: remove the 'E' from the beginning of each register name, change the DDs into DBs, increase their length by 4 times. remove the '*4' from the addressing modes of the mov and adc instructions. Then it should assemble for 8086.
You really need to read a book...

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways to do this. The first way is to do addition/subtraction directly on ASCII characters. In this case you can't just use the `ADC` and `SBB` instructions; and have to implement your own "for each digit" loop with your own "add/subtract digit" code.

The second way is to convert the user's ASCII into integers, then do addition/subtraction of integers, then convert the resulting integer back into ASCII (to display it). The ASCII to integer conversion involves multiplication of large integers by 10; and the integer to ASCII conversion involves division (and modulo) of large integers by 10.

For your case, the first way is faster (and probably easier), while the second way is going to make you learn more and be a better programmer.